# Inverse moments of a Beta distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $Y$ be a beta-distributed random variable, such that $Y \sim \mathrm{Beta}(N,LN-N)$. Is there any closed-form expression for the inverse moments of $Y$, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
 E\{Y^{-\alpha}\},\quad \alpha \in \mathbb{N}?
\end{equation*}
In particular, I'm interested in $E\{Y^{-3}\}$ and $E\{Y^{-4}\}$.

Thanks!

Comment: If $N \geq \alpha$, the integrand of $E[Y^{-\alpha}]$ has the same kernel as the pdf of $\text{Beta}(N-\alpha, LN-N)$ so the answer will be in terms of some gamma functions. If all of the $N, \alpha, LN-N$ are integers, then the resulting gamma functions can be further simplified. They can also be simplified if the fractional part is exactly $1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y\sim \text{Beta}(p,q)$. Then
$$
Y=_{d}\frac{Z}{Z+W}\tag{1}
$$
for some $Z\sim \text{Gamma}(p)$ and $W\sim \text{Gamma}(q)$ where $Z$ and W are independent ($p,q>0$). Further $Y$ is independent of the denominator $T=Z+W\sim \text{Gamma} (p+q)$. Here $=_{d}$ means equal in distribution and $Z\sim \text{Gamma}(p)$ means that $Z$ has density
$$
f_{Z}(z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}z^{p-1}e^{-z}\quad (z>0).
$$
In particular
$$
EZ^d=\Gamma(p+d)/\Gamma(p)
$$
for $d\in\mathbb{R}$. If $p+d\le0$, then $EZ^d=\infty$. From (1) it follows that
$$
EY^{d}ET^d=EZ^d\implies EY^d=\frac{\Gamma(p+d)}{\Gamma(p)}\bigg/\frac{\Gamma(p+q+d)}{\Gamma(p+q)}
$$
where $p+d>0$ and $p+q+d>0$.